Is there a Raydium Liquidity Pool List url for the new raydium-cp-swap?
For previous Raydium AMM's we had the following url for the Liquidity Pool List:
https://api.raydium.io/v2/sdk/liquidity/mainnet.json
Is there a similarly maintained url for the the new raydium-cp-swap (https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-cp-swap)?

This is the new API swagger with the endpoints:
https://api-v3.raydium.io/docs/
